# What is $(prefix) on $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig?

Tags: git, configuration, prefix, git-config

[gitconfig(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#FILES):

> If not set explicitly with --file, there are four files where git config will search for configuration options:
>
> ...
>
> **$(prefix)**/etc/gitconfig
>
> System-wide configuration file.

What is `$(prefix)` on `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `prefix` environment variable git was compiled with. Usually, it's `/usr/local`, so the path is `/usr/local/etc/gitconfig`.

More information can be found in the `INSTALL` file in the git repository.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? … What do you mean by “git was compiled”? Do you mean installed? How is the variable that “git was compiled with” specified? How does one see the value of this variable? How does one change it?

Comment: you supply it to the `configure` script before compiling git.

Comment: @Famaref Can you explain it like I have no idea what you’re talking about? Please edit your answer with more details. It’s worth an upvote.

Comment: have a look in the git repository in the INSTALL file. Details the build process.