# UTF-16 support in Git for Windows 2.x

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8, ssms, utf-16

I work in a team on a development project that includes files created in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). The default file encoding for SSMS is: *Codepage 1200 (Little-endian UTF-16)*.

Git for Windows recognises these files as binary. It is unable to show diff views of the files and it cannot merge files (remote merges *overwrite* the local version).

We are able to change the default encoding in SSMS easily. However, we prefer not to have risk of any UTF-16 files being committed - as they cause havoc in our source control and release mgmt processes.

[This stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915072/git-gui-can-it-be-made-to-display-utf16) describes how to use Clean/Smudge filters to convert UTF-16 files to UTF-8 on the fly when committed, using two tools by GnuWin32: `iconv`, `file`.

This works well and we have been using it with msysgit 1.9.5 preview for a long time. However, this version is deprecated and the newer Git has more and more features that we require as a team. The problem is that this workaround relies on updating two files: `Git\etc\gitattributes` and `Git\etc\gitconfig`. These 2 files do not exist in Git for Windows 2.x

How can I add UTF-16 support to Git 2.x? Either by adapting the workaround for described for Git 1.x or by any other means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure the 2 files, system-wide (i.e. all users and all repos) as follows:

#### gitconfig

In your git for windows shell:

`git config --system --edit`

#### gitattributes

`git config --system core.attributesfile <path>` 
and use whichever path you wish

Ofcourse, if you wish to reduce the scope to global (i.e. all repos for a specific user only) then, replace `--system` with `--global`.

Relevant questions: 
[Where should I place my global 'gitattributes' file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026767/where-should-i-place-my-global-gitattributes-file)

 [Where do the settings in my Git configuration come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756753/where-do-the-settings-in-my-git-configuration-come-from)

 [What is $(prefix) on $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713622/what-is-prefix-on-prefix-etc-gitconfig)

Comment: This is great, thanks. So I do still need to use `iconv` and `file` in a clean/smudge filter to enable utf-16 support? I'm surprised this isn't natively supported by now.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a global `gitattributes` and `gitconfig` is probably the best way to go.

Git for windows 2 is based on MSYS2. This has an `\etc` directory somewhere. The best way to access it is probably to open an MSYS2 shell.